# why checkbox listener method called not working?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

In the below code i wish to call afterscan method only when the checkboxer checkbox is clicked. but some how i have noticed that the method is called from all other checkbox once is checked. any help would be highly appreciated

class Chk_class implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{

```
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        result=new StringBuilder();

        if(checkBox2.isChecked())
        {
            result.append("Connection issue |");
        }
  
        if(checkBox4.isChecked())
        {
            result.append("Machnical issue |");
        }
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
        liftError=result.toString();

        if(checkBoxer.isChecked()){

            afterscan();  // this method is called from all other checkbox as well 
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: maybe check if `buttonView` is `checkBoxer` (if all checkboxes are using same listener)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using this method for all checkBoxes then you can do something like this(it is not a clean approach but it should fix the problem):

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

     .... 

    if(checkBoxer.isChecked()&&checkBoxer.getId()==buttonView.getId()){
        afterscan();  
    }


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

     .... 

    if(checkBoxer.isChecked()&&checkBoxer.getId()==buttonView.getId()){
        afterscan();  
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) will help people understand the reasons for your code suggestion.